# The usage of ものの

Tags: grammar, jlpt, word-usage

I have trouble understanding the usage of ものの in the following sentence:

> 病気が初期に見つかったからいい＿＿、もう少し発見が遅かったら命が危なかった。
>
> A. とばかりに
>
> B. かと思いきや
>
> C. というものの
>
> D. ようなものの

The right answer is D.

However, I think the answer should be C (according to [this](https://www.renshuu.org/grammar/161/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE)). I couldn't find any resources pointing out the usage of ようなものの.

Comment: @Brandon The most natural one is just ものの. You have to choose one that doesn't change the meaning as long as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @chocolate already cited in the comment, despite the looking, this question isn't actually asking about usage of "though", but knowledge of the idiom `X からいい（ような）ものの Y`, which roughly means "Just lucky that X, (otherwise) Y". I guess most native speakers would come up with this phrase when they've read to the part からいい.

For the possibility whether other choices could be true... well, purely grammatically speaking, C and B also have chances being "valid" (of course, only in very complicated situations that need a paragraph about the story so far). It however seems that they carefully chose wordings that none of other sound natural. If C were just ものの, the construction still works. Or it could be [とはいうものの](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/159821/meaning/m0u/), in this case it'd mean "X, that said, Y" and at least make sense.

---

**PS**
If you filled in C, the sentence would be like:

> Despite being said that it was okay because the disease was detected in early stage, my life would be threatened if the detection were just a little later.

or B:

> Contrary to expectation that it was okay because the disease was detected in early stage, my life would be threatened if the detection were just a little later.

Answer (score 1):

To me, D sounds more popular than C, but C is acceptable as well. In case of C, I prefer to say 病気が初期に見つかったからいいとはいうものの.