# Question about いいよう

Tags: meaning

In the following sentence, I'm confused about the meaning of いいよう:

> 今だって、留守番が下っ端のニコだったから
> **いいよう**なもの、他の連中だったら
> すぐに放り出されてるところだよ！

The context is that ニコ, a pirate, gave away a valuable treasure that belonged to the crew. The speaker is speaking to the person who received the treasure.

I found out that 言いよう can mean 'way of speaking', so is the speaker talking about ニコ's way of talking? Or does もの refer to the treasure, with いいよう describing it being in 'good form'?

Comment: Wasn't it もの**の**?

Comment: https://imgur.com/zJWViix

Comment: It should be ものの and this is related. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34182/43676

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in your example `"言いよう"` does not mean 'way of speaking'.

Here use is as below.

```
Sentence + からいいようなものの
```

Used in meaning as "This time something **has worked (anyway or say luckily) but** need to take care next time"

Therefore, in your sentence the house-sitter was Nico so it was good thing, otherwise there could have been issue.